# Matlab: Create 3D cube RGB and show it

Tags: matlab, 3d, matrix, show, rgb

I'll try to be precise and short.

I have a volume (128x128x128) and a mask (same size with [0|1|2] values)

I want to make the 3D volume matrix a 3D image with RGB, and store in each channel (red,green,blue) the points marked in the mask.

This is to use a 2D representation by taking a slice of that 3D cube, and not compute it over and over to make things way more faster (very important in my project), so actually, the 3D volume + rgb would be like a store for 128 2D images.

The question is, what steps and how do I have to make all this:
- Create a volume 128x128x128x3 ?
- Define a new colormap (original is gray) ?
- Join each channel ?
- How do I use imagesc/whatever to show one slice of that cube with the points in the color as marked in the mask (ex: imageRGB(:,:,64)) ?

That's just my guess, but I don't even know how to do it properly...I'm a bit lost, I hope you can help me, this is a piece of code that may be wrong but may help you out

```
% Create the matrix 4D
ovImg = zeros(size(volImg,1),size(volImg,2),size(volImg,3),3);    % 128x128x128x3
% Store in each channel the points marked as groups
ovImg(:,:,:,1) = volImg .* (mask==1);
ovImg(:,:,:,2) = volImg .* (mask==2);
ovImg(:,:,:,3) = volImg .* (mask==3);
```

many many thanks!!

UPDATE:

I'm having some trouble with transparency and the colormap, this is what I did.

```
% Create the matrix 4D
ovImg = zeros(size(volImg,1),size(volImg,2),size(volImg,3),3);
% Store in each channel the points marked as groups
ovImg(:,:,:,1) = imaNorm.*(mask==1);
ovImg(:,:,:,2) = imaNorm.*(mask==2);
ovImg(:,:,:,3) = imaNorm.*(mask==3);

[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:128,1:128,1:128);
imaNorm = volImg - min(volImg(:));   
maxval = max(imaNorm(:));        
ovImg  = imaNorm + mask * maxval;


N= ceil(maxval);
c = [linspace(0,1,N)' zeros(N,2)];
my_colormap = [c(:,[1 2 3]) ; c(:,[3 1 2]) ; c(:,[2 3 1])];

figure;
imshow(squeeze(ovImg(:,:,64)),my_colormap);

figure;
imagesc(squeeze(mask(:,:,64)));
```

Result (Overlayed image / mask)
[image: Overlayed and mask picture]
Any ideas? Thanks again, everybody

---

FINAL UPDATE:
With the other approach that Gunther Struyf suggested, I had exactly what I wanted.
Thanks mate, I really appreciate it, hope this helps other people too.

Comment: You're mask has three values, so do they then correspond with three colors? So when you finally plot a slice, it'll only have three colors in it? You also say you have a 3D volume matrix; what values does it contain then? the density at location `(x(i), y(j), z(k))` ? Or do you mean you have a position matrix? In that case, what are the x,y and z here? Or are they just evenly spaced eg `1:128`?

Comment: The matrix, is the result of reading a nifti image with spm_read_vols(spm_vol(path)), so it contains the bright value in each position of the 3D space. Then I will have a mask with 3 different areas, which I want to show in a different colour each of them creating the same structure, but with RGB values stored in 3D so then I can take a slice of it and have it directly coloured.
It's like a pile of 2D RGB images coloured as the mask is marked from which I'll take one at a time.

Comment: you'll have to understand the relation between your data and the colormap, read the documentation carefully! I think we're pretty close though: Can you try again with `N=ceil(max(ovImg(:)))` ?

Comment: If I do that it just shows everything as red (brighter or darker, but just red).

Comment: Also notice that blue is not transparent and I can't see what's underneath it

Comment: oops, I meant `N=ceil(max(ovImg(:))/3)`. But I think we can try a different approach now I reread your question, expect another answer soon!

Comment: btw, you're talking about transparancy, but in all code on this page, there is nothing which involves transparancy, just selecting a subset of the whole color spectrum for a specific subset of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [imshow](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/images/ref/imshow.html) with a [colormap](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html) to 'fake' an RGB image from a grayscale image (which you have). For the scale I'd not multiply it, but add an offset to the value, so each mask is a different range in the colormap.

For plotting a slice of the 3d matrix, you can just index it and then [squeeze](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/squeeze.html) it to remove the resulting singleton dimension:

Example:

```
[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(1:128,1:128,1:128);
volImg =5*sin(X/3)+13*cos(Y/5)+8*sin(Z/10);
volImg=volImg-min(volImg(:));
mask = repmat(floor(linspace(0,3-2*eps,128))',[1 128 128]);

maxval=max(volImg(:));
ovImg=volImg+mask*maxval;
imshow(squeeze(ovImg(:,:,1)),jet(ceil(max(ovImg(:)))));
```

Unmasked, original image (`imshow(squeeze(volImg(:,:,1)),jet(ceil(maxval)))`)

[image]

Resulting with mask (code block above):

[image]

For different colormaps, see [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html), or create your own colormap. Eg you're mask has three values, so let's match those with R,G and B:

```
N = ceil(maxval);
c = [linspace(0,1,N)' zeros(N,2)];
my_colormap = [c(:,[1 2 3]) ; c(:,[3 1 2]) ; c(:,[2 3 1])];
figure
imshow(squeeze(ovImg(:,:,1)),my_colormap);
```

which gives:

[image]

### Other approach:

Now I understand your question, I see you got it quite right from the beginning, you only need rescale the variable to a value between 0 and 1, since from [imshow](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/images/ref/imshow.html):

> Color intensity can be specified on the interval 0.0 to 1.0.

which you can do using:

```
minval=min(volImg(:));
maxval=max(volImg(:));
volImg=(volImg-minval)/(maxval-minval);
```

next up is your code:

```
ovImg = zeros([size(volImg),3]);
ovImg(:,:,:,1) = volImg .* (mask==1);
ovImg(:,:,:,2) = volImg .* (mask==2);
ovImg(:,:,:,3) = volImg .* (mask==3);
```

You just have to plot it now:

```
imshow(squeeze(ovImg(:,:,64,:)))
```

Comment: I've just tried your code and understood your explanation but I have some doubts, I hope it's not asking too much.

I'm having some trouble with transparency and colours, I update my post with some pictures so you can see what's happening.

And I'm very very grateful to you, thanks for your time and answer, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, now that was absolutely perfect.
Thanks again, you've been very heplful :) THANKS